# How to calculate the base 2 log of a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, logarithm

The only function that I found that calculates the log of the matrix, and not of each component of the matrix, was scipy's [logm()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.logm.html) function, but it finds the log with base e, I need the base 2 log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the change-of-base formula to convert the base of the logarithm:

`log2(x) = logm(x) / logm(2)`

Mathematica StackExchange has some more in depth discussion of the math behind this:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92293